# why fgets function is not ending for a NULL pointer while using with malloc()?

Tags: c, malloc, fgets

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct island
{
    char *name;
    char *opens;
    char *closes;
    struct island *next;
} island ;

island* create(char *name){

    island *i = malloc(sizeof(island));
    i->name =strdup (name);
    i->opens ="09:00";
    i->closes ="17:00";
    i->next = NULL;
    return i;
}

void display(island *start){
        island *i = start;
        for (; i != NULL ; i = i->next)
            printf("Name: %s open: %s-%s\n",i->name,i->opens,i->closes);
}
void release(island *start){
        island *i = start;
        island *next = NULL;
        for (; i != NULL; i = next) {
            next =i->next;
            free(i->name);
            free(i);
        }
}


int main(){
    freopen("in.txt","r",stdin);
    char name[80];

    island *start = NULL;
    island *i = NULL;
    island *next = NULL;

    for(;fgets(name, 80, stdin)!=NULL; i =next) {
        next = create(name);
        if (start == NULL)
            start =next;
        if (i != NULL)
            i->next= next;
    }
    display(start);
    release(start);

    //display(p_island0);
    //display(&amity);
    return 0;
}
```

In my code it should return a list of names with their correspondent values which is string literals. what I am not getting is that at the end of my output i am getting an extra name field which is blank. I have used fgets and conditioned it with NULL. but still it is counting a blank space as an input. I know fgets returns NULL on error or when end of file occurs while no characters have been read but in my case it is still not terminated while it gets a NULL. why is this? i have given my input file and corresponding output.

This is my input file used in code as "in.txt"

```
Atlantis
Santa
Barbara 
Modi
Ludio
```

This is my output.

```
Name: atlantis
open: 09:00-17:00
Name: santa
open: 09:00-17:00
Name: Barbara 
open: 09:00-17:00
Name: Modi
open: 09:00-17:00
Name: Ludio
open: 09:00-17:00
Name: 
open: 09:00-17:00
```

Comment: Seems that `in.txt` haves an extra newline

Comment: Thanks..i noticed it after you mentioned. it had an extra indexed line and i removed it and it works... great! thanks!